# Selenium, Safari: Only take screenshot of the visible elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Using Selenium to test website, I want to take screenshot of the visible part of the page (the viewport).

In Chrome, firefox and opera by default it's like this.
in IE I added a capability:

```
"ie.enableFullPageScreenshot": false
```

in Safari, I can't find a way to do it.

Also I want to avoid cropping the screenshot.

Comment: Is Safari giving you a full page screenshot?

Comment: Yes, that's the case

Comment: @ElheniMokhles How? When I do `browser.save_screenshot(url)`with safari's webdriver, it only takes a screenshot of the viewable part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

May be :-

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(targetSize);
```

Source :-

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3752

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: that's the inverse of what I want